# Metaio LocationBasedAR position 0,0

Tags: sdk, augmented-reality, metaio

I download Metaio SDK and i start LocationBasedAR tutorial but if I tap on Paris (for example) i get my position 0,0. GPS works fine. Someone had the same problem? Is it a bug of Metaio?

Comment: can you please give me the link, where to download metaio sdk for android.

Comment: In Metaio Dashboard, you must login in Metaio Developer Portal

Answer (score 0):

That happens if you tap on label. Try to tap on POI image, then you should get actual coordinates.